# Should I debounce everything?

Tags: debounce, switch-debouncing

I am a newbie in electrical engineering and recently learnt about debouncing. While it's obvious why I should debounce a push button that is connected to a microcontroller, I'm wondering why there are very few mentions of debouncing when it comes to other pieces of electrical equipment that are turned on/off by some kind of mechanical switch. For example:

- LEDs
- audio amplifiers
- nixie tubes (i.e. should I debounce them with some kind of capacitor when the power is controlled via switch?)
- incandescent lamps (shouldn't we care about inrush current when the lamp is cold???)
- etc.

My intuition is that if we don't debounce, we can somehow damage the components, because they are turned on/off very rapidly.

When should I debounce, and what are the aspects I should know/consider to understand that hardware debouncing is necessary in any particular case?

Comment: It would help to answer why in the first place you would debounce a pushbutton. I mean, it does not make any sense to always debounce every pushbutton you connect to a MCU. And do you mean hardware or software debouncing?

Comment: @Justme my main concern was that longevity of the hardware components might decrease if we don't do hardware debouncing. Thanks to the answers I know understand that it is not the case (at least with some simple components). The question was not about MCUs in particular :)

Comment: OK so how do you think the hardware debouncing relates to hardware longevity? Of course it depends what you control but still. Sometimes hardware debouncing is bad because it slows down signals. Depends on how you do the hardware debounce of course.

Comment: @justme I meant whether we need some measures to protect the circuitry against the negative effects of contact bounce to improve its longevity (see Fredled's answer)

Comment: Yes, contact bounce can produce harmful spikes in addition to just making a circuit detect multiple pushes. You can either protect without debouncing, or debounce without protecting, they do not necessarily come simultaneously.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We de-bounce when the extra transitions might trigger something unwanted.  You have identified one of those cases:  A microcontroller reading a pushbutton.

In most cases, we don't care if there is a very brief period of "bouncing".

LEDs and lamps aren't harmed by the voltage momentarily flickering when switching, and since usually this effect is so fast the human eye cannot see it, there is no incentive to take steps to remove it.  Incandescent lamps turn on very slowly anyway (compared to the time frame of the bouncing).

Audio amplifiers will often have circuitry which acts as a "slow start" to avoid loud pops on the output.  I suppose you could think of this as a type of de-bouncing.

Nixie tubes, like incandescent lamps, are slow to turn on as well.  They don't need de-bouncing.

The bouncing that a pushbutton does is unlikely to damage anything.  You want to de-bounce when the bounces themselves can trigger an unwanted event (over-counting the number of button presses, for example)

Comment: In addition to the answer: many power switches has mechanical debounce, they say "click" when switched.

Comment: LEDs of course are often run pulsed on comparable timescales to switch bounce anyway, to control their brightness/average current with PWM

Answer (score 3):

There are two things that come together with hardware debouncing:

1. Offering a clear logical signal instead of multiple up and downs
2. Protecting the I/O pins and/or subsequent devices.

Often, protection will debounce and debouncing will protect. Debouncing is not only smoothing down the signal, it also reduces peak voltages above supply voltage. These peak voltages are very short, and may never be enough high or long to damage an IC but it's always a good thing to suppress them.
Same with negative current which can appear on both sides of the switch, before or after it has been pressed or released. Negative current can be more harmful than short peak voltage.
These two effects can be generated by metallic parts hitting each other or when suddenly losing contact with each other, and spring effects.

In this respect, non-logic devices like LED can be *debounced*, in the sense of *protected*.

The first schematic shows an input with the most basic protection and already a beginning of debouncing. Please note the presence of a resistor before and after the switch. Limit the current as much as possible with R1.
R3 keeps the input low when disconnected.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDzPHp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Staring from there, you can add a variety of discrete components which improve protection or debouncing or both. D1 removes negative current which can appear when the switch is released or pressed but not yet completely pressed, C1  will debounce the signal by smoothing and protect the input by absorbing excess voltage. Z1 is the ultimate protection. C2 is used as a reservoir capacitor and can also absorb excess voltage if any, protecting the supply. If you want you can add varistors between R1 and R2. Varistors protect from very high voltage excess (not from small excess) but can help debouncing thanks to their capacitance.

Or, to the contrary, remove some components if you think it's too much or if it degrades the signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZGb3B.png)</sup>

If the line powers something (here a LED but it can be anything), you can use practically the same circuit, without the resistors, and removing the zener or replacing it by a varistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4koQX.png)</sup>

Comment: Maybe you could give an example of a circuit that does protection and debouncing? Or explain from where the negative current would come? And if the signal is smoothed, how will the smoothed signal can then give clear logical signals?

Comment: Yes. I will try to find the time to do that tomorrow.

Comment: Just a minor note, R1 is rather large compared to R3 making a questionable logic output level, and LED1 doesn't show resistance (a general load might be better shown as a resistor RL?). You might also show, on the last one say, the inductance for which the switch (and subsequent capacitance) can produce inrush; an auto-closing switch can even be used to make a representative simulation of it.

Comment: Yes, values are for indication only and can be adapted. Of the supply is 3V, R1 can be 4.7K and R3 470K for example. If supply is 12V (assuming the input supports that voltage) then R1 can be 33K and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Debouncing is required on switch or relay inputs to digital logic or microcontrollers, as the switch or relay contacts will bounce (rapidly turn on and off a few times) rather than closing cleanly.  This bounce action can confuse logic circuits - if the switch closure is intended to increment a counter, the counter may show several counts as the switch bounces for one actual press.

For the LEDs, nixie tubes and other things you mention, we don't care if they make a few brief flashes as they turn on or off, so debouncing is not needed.